# VLC fullscreen progress bar is over subtitles

Tags: video, vlc-media-player, overlay

Since version 3.x (as I recall) VLC is packed with a nice colored overlay progress bar in full-screen. Progress bar which I would love to modify to avoid it being displayed **OVER** subtitles when I search across a movie (e.g. fast forwarding with ctrl + right arrow).

[image: Screenshot of the problem]

I can't find any way to change the position or better: the alpha/transparency of that bar.

Please forgive my English and thanks for any tips regarding my problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the only way available to avoid that is [disabling the OSD](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=144409), [(2)](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?t=145719) (On-Screen Display) which is not ideal but it will prevent the bar overlaying the subtitles.

It's not possible to change its color either.

There is also a [ticket](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/22574) requesting the feature if you want to keep track of it.

Note that disabling the OSD will also disable other features such as the subtitle filename, volume information, etc.

---

This problem was [also reported](https://forum.videolan.org/viewtopic.php?f=12&t=144706&p=474568#p474568) a year ago with the goal of changing the position of the progress bar to the top and it's planned to get fixed in the upcoming version 4.0.0 ([#20684](https://trac.videolan.org/vlc/ticket/20684)) planned to be completed on 1 Oct 2019.

The first ticket I mentioned doesn't have any date planned but this ticket should solve the main problem.

Comment: That's what I feared. Thank's for your help anyway and I'll follow the ticket.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way round these blue progress and volume bars with the interface style setting bright / dark. But there's a bug.
Here's a lengthy description:

1) Start up VLC fresh. Preferences default interface style "Bright"
In full screen mode electric blue progress and volume bars appear and can't be removed.

2) Preferences, set interface style "dark". 
Save.
Restart VLC.
Behaviour unchanged : Electric blue progress bars persist in full screen.

3) Set interface style via detailed menus :
Restart VLC ; Preferences ; "Show all" ; "Interface" ; 
"macosx" => set "Run VLC with dark interface style" the first, topmost option.
Save again.
Restart.
Blue electric bars persist.

4) Finally : The solution.
Restart VLC
Preferences : This time "Reset all" and restart.
Now set the interface style via the detailed menus and NOT via the basic preferences option. To repeat the step above :
Set interface style via detailed menus :
Restart VLC ; Preferences ; "Show all" ; "Interface" ; 
"macosx" => set "Run VLC with dark interface style" the first, topmost option.
Save again.
Restart.

Hmm : It doesn't work any more. I feel somewhat foolish but I'll post this anyway.

There is a big here : Doing something along those steps listed above, I did at one point manage to end up with a dark interface which did not show the impossible electric blue progress and volume bars in full screen.

While acknowledging all the hard work done by the excellent Videolan programmers, would it be possible to remove this electric blue? Replace with a plain discreet frame?
Or remove entirely and keep only a number ?